# Update form with image size using Jquery after page is loaded

Tags: php, jquery, image-size

I've tested multiple instances of my code, but there are some inconsistency that I can't figure out. So I hope you smart guys can help.

I have this jquery code in the header

```
function real_image_size () {
    var img = document.getElementById('target'); 
    //or however you get a handle to the IMG
    var real_width = img.clientWidth;
    var real_height = img.clientHeight;

    $('#rw').attr('value', real_width);
    $('#rh').attr('value', real_height);

}
```

I have this html/php code that I want to update with the dimensions of the displayed image

```
<img width="1000px" class="crop_img" id="target" src="$image_address" />


<form action="/save_cropped_image.php" method="post" onsubmit="checkCoords();">
      <input type="text" size="4" id="image_source" name="image_source" hidden="hidden" value="$image_address" />
      <input id="x" name="x" />
      <input id="y" name="y" />
      <input id="w" name="w" />
      <input id="h" name="h" />
      <input id="rw" name="rw" />
      <input id="rh" name="rh" />
      <input type="submit" value="Lagre nytt bilde" />
</form>
```

When the page is rendered I'm running a script to populate the input fields `rw` and `rh` with the dimensions of the displayed image `$target`.

My problem is that the `rw` is updated correctly, but the `rh` is always updated to "2". When the page is rendered the first time.

If I choose another image from my drop down box (not described in the code). Then the script updates the `#image` and then both `rw` and `rh` are updated correctly using the same function `(image_size_update())` and not just `rw`....

```
</script>

    <script>
    $(window).ready(real_image_size());

</script>
```

----- UPDATE ------

I've tried to add setTimeout on the function after image loaded. But with no change... still getting the wrong rh (real_image_height)

```
$('#target').load(setTimeout(real_image_size(),10000));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is a simple - but very inconspicuous - one. Effectively, on load, your image might not be loaded yet. The browser already knows the width of it (as it stays constant throughout and probably has already rendered at least part of the image), but not the total height.

What you will need to do is to stagger the JS call until your first image is fully loaded. This can be done using a loaded() event using jQuery, or in plain JavaScript using an onLoad event (they're one and the same). This should give you the correct values.

Comment: I can't any loaded() event using jQuery, are you refering to load()?

onload="real_image_size();" on the <img /> itself - gives none of the value (rw or rh)

Comment: I am indeed referring to load. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 1):

try `$(window).load` instead of `ready`

Comment: Hi, It seems to be an issue with Safari as Firefox updates rh correctly

Comment: Neither of the below works;

$('#target').load(real_image_size());
$('window').load(real_image_size());